# How to modify font using MailApp Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script that sends mail using [`MailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) but I can't find how to change the font.

I am using this format:

```js
var subject = xxxxxx;
var body = 'xxxxxx' + var + 'xxxxx' + var + 'xxxx';
var recipient = xxxxxx;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
```

How do I modify the body style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can do it with the advanced parameter [htmlBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Sample:

```
  var body='<p style = "font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;"> xxxxxx </p> ';
  var subject = 'xxxxxx';
  var recipient = 'xxxxxx';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,"",{htmlBody: body});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have multiple entries in my body with calls of different variables. Is there a way to apply the style to the entire body ?

Comment: Sure: e.g. `var body='<p style = "font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;">'+body1+body2+body3+'</p> ';`

Comment: I have modify my post to better illustrate how I've written it : `var body = 'xxxxxx' + var + 'xxxxx' + var + 'xxxx';` It would work with your suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, `var body='<p style = "font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;">'+'xxxxxx' + var + 'xxxxx' + var + 'xxxx'+'</p> ';`

Comment: This answer helped